# Social plugin for Wordpress not using 'postname'

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to use the '[Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/)' plugin from MailChimp on a Wordpress blog. Everything is setup fine and it works perfectly, except one aspect.

When I use the 'Broadcast' feature or leave a comment and post to Twitter/Facebook it creates a URL with the 'Post-ID' `http://domain.com/blog/?p=1` instead of using the 'postname' `http://domain.com/blog/post-name/` which I setup in the permalinks section of Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in filters to create plugin that will adjust the URL format, however the ?p=123 style URLs are the default (and highly recommended) to help get more meaningful content into the broadcast.

Comment: Probably going to be above my skill level at the moment and if its highly recommended to leave it as the default that's what I'll do. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing in file "/wp-content/plugins/social/lib/social/service.php" the line (appears only one time in the file)

`$url = wp_get_shortlink($post->ID);`

for:

`$url = get_post_permalink($post->ID);`

You must test carefully that the change doesn't affect any other functionality, maybe contacting to the plugin creator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made the change but its still outputting the same URL. I'll keep digging in these files see if I can find anything similar.

Comment: Infact, its outputting the same URL when I add a comment and post to Twitter. But if I use the 'Broadcast' feature, the URL is changing to http://domain.com/blog/?post_type=post&p=1 instead of being http://domain.com/blog/?p=1

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to match the url's and broadcast it. It still does not works.
The problem is only when you use a featured image to broadcast it.

It works better (not 100%) for a post that is broadcasted without a featured image.

The problem is only with facebook. It does a good job with twitter.